# Convert int to float in array

Tags: int

The question ask to Write a C program that reads an integer array with M elements (M is read from the user). The program will print the original array with 3 decimal places per value, then count the number of odds and evens in the given array.
I use Dev-c by the way

**My code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    int M,i,even=0,odd=0;
    int a[M];
    float b[M];

    printf("Input array size:");
    scanf(" %d",&M);
    for (i=0;i<M;i++){
        printf("With a[%d]=",i);
       scanf(" %d",&a);        
    }
    printf("Original array:");
    for (i=0;i<M;i++){
        b[i]=(float)a;
       printf(" %.3f",b);
    }
    }
```

The problem:if I input 4, the output is ok. But when I input 5 or more the output shows this:

Input array size:9

With a[0]=1

With a[1]=2 ... With a[8]=9

Original array: 1.000 2.000 3.000 4.000 ***0.000 0.000*** 7.000 8.000 9.000

**What is wrong?**

Comment: There is something really wrong in your code: you declare a[M] and b[M] arrays with uninstantiated m. You need to use dynamic allocation for variable-length arrays. (malloc(M * sizeof int); for a, after M has been read.) (The array a is never used tho, but the issue still lies within use of b)

Comment: Why would you print _integers_ with decimal places?

Comment: @Alceste sorry, I overthinking, as Fretshot rewrite it 
I just need to put
 printf("%.3f",(float)a[i]); 
But that doesn't explain the problem in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Errors in your code where:-
>   1. Uninstantiated M
>   2. No use of even and odd

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
int M,i;
printf("Input array size:");
scanf(" %d",&M);
int a[M];
float b[M];
for (i=0;i<M;i++){
    printf("With a[%d]= ",i);
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
printf("Original array:");
for (i=0;i<M;i++){
    b[i]=(float)a[i];
   printf(" %.3f",b[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank for solving the problem, and sorry the code is not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

    void main(){
        int M,i,even=0,odd=0;
        int a[M];
        float b[M];

        printf("Input array size:");
        scanf(" %d",&M);
        for (i=0;i<M;i++){
            printf("With a[%d]=",i);
           scanf("%d",&a[i]);        
        }

         printf("Original array:");
        for (i=0;i<M;i++){
           printf("%.3f",(float)a[i]);
           printf(" ");
        }

        }
```

Comment: The output is still :
Original array: 1.000 2.000 3.000 4.000 0.000 0.000 7.000 8.000 9.000

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loops, you need to specify the index for a[i] as well.

You have created arrays a & b of size M, even though M has not been initialized yet. Does that work? Maybe you should put int a[M]; and float b[M]; after you have read in  the value of M.